# Queryset with different datasets based on obj type

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to implement in my application something similar to instagram's local notifications.
The main problem is that local notifications can be different types. For example:

1) Simple one: "`user` started following you" (this is pretty straightforward)

2) More complicated: "`user` and +7 other liked your photo X"

The first step of solution is to GROUP all notifications by `targeted_user`, `event_type` and `user_who_triggered_event`. For the first case it's okay as we will have all information. For the second case we will lack some information as Count of similar notifications. Also what if I need some additional information about those `+7` user's who also liked photo X?

**What I've tried:**

I've tried to use GROUP BY which can work for the second case but is not okay for the first. Also I tried to do 2 separate querysets which has all needed data for each type of notification. But then I'll have a problem that I cannot combine them and also cannot use pagination. Also if I'll return 2 querysets it will be hard for front-end to sort them by datetime

The first queryset:

ReceivedNotification.objects.filter(user=user)

The second one:
ReceivedNotification.objects.filter(user=user, notification__event=Notification.LIKED_PHOTO).values_list('receiver', 'notification__event')

```
class Notification(TimeStampedModel):
    OPEN_PROFILE = 'open_profile'
    OPEN_PHOTO = 'open_photo'
    ACTION_CHOICES = (
        (OPEN_PROFILE, _('Open profile')),
        (OPEN_PHOTO, _('Open photo')),
    )

    LIKED_PHOTO = 'liked_photo'
    NEW_FOLLOWER = 'new_follower'


    EVENT_CHOICES = (
        (LIKED_PHOTO, _('Liked photo')),
        (NEW_FOLLOWER, _('New follower'))
    )
    action = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=ACTION_CHOICES,
    )
    event = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=EVENT_CHOICES,
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
    )
    body = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'notifications'
```

For this example I have 2 notifications in data base.

Also I have `ReceivedNotification` model with FK to user and FK to notification and also data field(JSONField) to store actual information
which particular user will get.

Expected result is to get all local notifications for particular user is a single query.
Some notifications should have only basic info and other should have Counter of similar notifications if there are more than 3 similar and also list of Id's of that users.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @dirkgroten How to get all local notifications for user where each type of notifications will have their own dataset?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: @dirkgroten I've tried to use GROUP BY which can work for the second case but is not okay for the first. Also I tried to do 2 separate querysets which has all needed  data for each type of notification. But then I'll have a problem that I cannot combine them and also cannot use pagination. Also if I'll return 2 querysets it will be hard for front-end to sort them by datetime

Comment: Please edit your question to share the code you just mentioned so we get a better understanding of what you've tried and what was wrong with it.

Comment: @dirkgroten Added more information

Comment: Have you looked at [`union()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#union) which allows you to combine multiple querysets (and still sort/paginate etc... afterwards)? Or [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q)

Comment: @dirkgroten The union operation can be performed only with the querysets having same fields and the datatypes.
My querysets will have some different columns

Comment: Add empty columns to the queryset that doesn't have them so that the querysets are compatible. Otherwise you'll never be able to get it all in one query anyway.